# How to get AWS S3 redirection rule JSON syntax working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My JSON AWS S3 redirection rules aren't working, I keep getting the error "Expected params.WebsiteConfiguration.RoutingRules to be an Array". To me the below code looks syntactically correct.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
{
    "IndexDocument": {
        "Suffix": "index.html"
    },
    "ErrorDocument": {
        "Key": "404.html"
    },
    "RoutingRules": [
        {
            "Redirect": {
                "ReplaceKeyWith": "index.html"
            },
            "Condition": {
                "KeyPrefixEquals": "/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're updating the bucket from the **AWS console**.

When you update from the console you only pass the array for the routing rules, like so:

```
[
    {
        "Redirect": {
            "ReplaceKeyWith": "index.html"
        },
        "Condition": {
            "KeyPrefixEquals": "/"
        }
    }
]
```

Index and Error fields are defined on separate fields above the routing rules, and then AWS creates the final json that's passed to the API behind the scenes.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkXdQ.png)

If you use the API directly (CLI or SDKs) then you need pass the whole object like you did.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. As for the part about defining the Index and Error fields, how would I go about adding those in with the correct syntax? Every syntax I try doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Index and Error fields are defined separetely in the AWS Console.

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/RAqvUh4.png